# xrandr does not detect HDMI port

Tags: linux, laptop, multiple-monitors, hdmi

I have an Asus Scar II laptop running both Windows 10 and Mint 19. The HDMI port works and I have dual monitors in Windows. In Linux, xrandr detects my main display - eDP-1 connected primary - but does not detect the HDMI port at all.

My laptop has an RTX 2070 and it is my understanding that the laptop dedicated graphics works differently than the desktop variant. I believe that the GPU renders the image and then passes it off to the Intel gpu which then sends an image to the screen. As a result, I have read that the laptops use a different driver. Something I was reading about when preparing to do CUDA processing.

I don't understand the display system of Linux well enough to mess around on my own. Most of the ideas/solutions I have found deal with older versions of Linux and have proven ineffective.

What information can I provide to help?

Update:

The following is a link is a link to the webpage that I bought my laptop from. That said, I have tried to answer your questions specifically here and only include it for reference. https://www.amazon.ca/dp/B07N3LGZL9/ref=pe_3034960_233709270_TE_item

The graphics are as follows:
1) Integrated - UHD 630 (based on specs sheet for i7-8750H)
2) Dedicated - NVidia RTX 2070 (full laptop card, not max-q)

The results of " dmesg | grep 'drm' " are:

```
[    1.695943] [drm] Memory usable by graphics device = 4096M
[    1.695945] fb: switching to inteldrmfb from EFI VGA
[    1.696082] [drm] Replacing VGA console driver
[    1.702139] [drm] Supports vblank timestamp caching Rev 2 (21.10.2013).
[    1.702139] [drm] Driver supports precise vblank timestamp query.
[    1.706007] [drm] Finished loading DMC firmware i915/kbl_dmc_ver1_01.bin (v1.1)
[    1.716662] [drm] Initialized i915 1.6.0 20171023 for 0000:00:02.0 on minor 0
[    1.720894] fbcon: inteldrmfb (fb0) is primary device
[    1.720935] i915 0000:00:02.0: fb0: inteldrmfb frame buffer device
[    2.812413] [drm] RC6 on
```

I belive that I have a driver issue at the very least. I'm not convinced that Linux sees the NVidia card as what it is. During my attempts to identify what driver I used the command "sudo lshw -c video" with the resulting output:

```
sudo lshw -c video
  *-display UNCLAIMED       
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: NVIDIA Corporation
       vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       version: a1
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress vga_controller bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:a4000000-a4ffffff memory:90000000-9fffffff memory:a0000000-a1ffffff ioport:4000(size=128) memory:a5000000-a507ffff
  *-display
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: Intel Corporation
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 00
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pciexpress msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
       resources: irq:131 memory:a3000000-a3ffffff memory:80000000-8fffffff ioport:5000(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff
```

I do not know how to obtain the correct laptop driver for NVidia cards. I have checked the Driver Manager and it shows no options.

Comment: Could you copy the "drm"-related messages from `dmesg`? What GPU models does this system have? Are you using proprietary drivers for either of the GPUs? Your understanding of laptop dual-GPU systems seems right, but that's something Linux drivers already support.

Comment: I updated the question to provide the information you requestion.

Comment: `display UNCLAIMED` is the issue here. The reason for that is likely having Secure Boot enabled in UEFI. Just like your more recent question it shows that you need to learn a few thing in order to properly install and use a dual-boot.