# XRandR does not see HDMI monitor on laptop (Arch linux)

Tags: laptop, multiple-monitors, hdmi, nvidia-graphics-card, xorg

I Have a Dell G3 3779 laptop shipped with GTX1050Ti, with Arch linux and i3-wm, and I want to connect HDMI monitor to it. As far as i know (correct me if i'm wrong), even on windows there is no way to run main display on GTX, as well as there is no way to run HDMI monitor on integrated graphics card, however windows combines them just fine. In my xorg.conf I have:

```
Section "ServerLayout"
    Identifier     "X.org Configured"
    Screen      0  "Screen0" 0 0
    Screen      1  "Screen1" LeftOf "Screen0"
    InputDevice    "Mouse0" "CorePointer"
    InputDevice    "Keyboard0" "CoreKeyboard"
EndSection

Section "Files"
    ModulePath   "/usr/lib/xorg/modules"
    FontPath     "/usr/share/fonts/misc"
    FontPath     "/usr/share/fonts/TTF"
    FontPath     "/usr/share/fonts/OTF"
    FontPath     "/usr/share/fonts/Type1"
    FontPath     "/usr/share/fonts/100dpi"
    FontPath     "/usr/share/fonts/75dpi"
EndSection

Section "Module"
    Load  "glx"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier   "Monitor0"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier   "Monitor1"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier  "Card0"
    Driver      "intel"
    BusID       "PCI:0:2:0"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier  "Card1"
    Driver      "nvidia"
    BusID       "PCI:1:0:0"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier "Screen0"
    Device     "Card0"
    Monitor    "Monitor0"
    SubSection "Display"
        Viewport   0 0
        Depth     1
    EndSubSection
    SubSection "Display"
        Viewport   0 0
        Depth     4
    EndSubSection
    SubSection "Display"
        Viewport   0 0
        Depth     8
    EndSubSection
    SubSection "Display"
        Viewport   0 0
        Depth     15
    EndSubSection
    SubSection "Display"
        Viewport   0 0
        Depth     16
    EndSubSection
    SubSection "Display"
        Viewport   0 0
        Depth     24
    EndSubSection
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier "Screen1"
    Device     "Card1"
    Monitor    "Monitor1"
    SubSection "Display"
        Viewport   0 0
        Depth     1
    EndSubSection
    SubSection "Display"
        Viewport   0 0
        Depth     4
    EndSubSection
    SubSection "Display"
        Viewport   0 0
        Depth     8
    EndSubSection
    SubSection "Display"
        Viewport   0 0
        Depth     15
    EndSubSection
    SubSection "Display"
        Viewport   0 0
        Depth     16
    EndSubSection
    SubSection "Display"
        Viewport   0 0
        Depth     24
    EndSubSection
EndSection
```

(I omitted everything unrelated to monitors) 
With this configuration, it only outputs to my main monitor, and `xrandr -q` outputs the following:

```
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 32767 x 32767
eDP1 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 380mm x 210mm
   1920x1080     60.13*+  59.93    48.07  
   <other resolution info>
DP1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
VIRTUAL1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

The important thing to note is that my mouse CAN go to the other display, and I can see it showing as a black cross, but i can't do anything with it.
If i change one line of xorg.conf for Device with `Identifier "Card0"` as following: 
`driver    "intel"` -> `driver    "nvidia"` 
then it starts outputting only to my HDMI monitor, and first monitor shows tty as it was before running `startx`. the output of `xrandr -q` in that case:

```
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 1360 x 768, maximum 32767 x 32767
HDMI-0 connected primary 1360x768+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 160mm x 90mm
   1360x768      60.02*+
   1920x1080     59.94    50.00    29.97    25.00    23.98    60.05    60.00    50.04  
   1280x720      60.00    59.94    50.00  
   1024x768      75.03    70.07    60.00  
   800x600       75.00    72.19    60.32  
   720x576       50.00  
   720x480       59.94  
   640x480       75.00    72.81    59.94
```

It does not output information about any other displays at all, it only sees one display (the bad resolution is not the problem since this is an old TV). Also, the mouse, unlike with previous config, can not go to the second monitor.

So the question is: How to configure Xorg in such a way that xrandr outputs on both my monitors? One related answer that I found was about Ubuntu: 
 https://askubuntu.com/questions/796827/hdmi1-is-disconnected 
and it didn't work for me. Moreover, my Microsoft edge completely broke until I reinstalled nvidia drivers (it was showing random pixels). I also tried installing bumblebee, but didn't go too far with it. Both config files were originally generated automatically, one with `Xorg --configure` (that outputs to main display) and other with `nvidia-xconfig` (that outputs to HDMI display). for additional info, the result of running `lspci -k | grep -A 2 -E "(VGA|3D)"`:

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation CoffeeLake-H GT2 [UHD Graphics 630]
    DeviceName: Onboard - Video
    Subsystem: Dell CoffeeLake-H GT2 [UHD Graphics 630]
--
01:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GP107M [GeForce GTX 1050 Ti Mobile] (rev a1)
    Subsystem: Dell GP107M [GeForce GTX 1050 Ti Mobile]
    Kernel driver in use: nvidia
```

I do use dual booting, but secure boot is disabled (question [xrandr does not detect HDMI port](https://superuser.com/questions/1433400/xrandr-does-not-detect-hdmi-port))

Comment: I did not try to enable drm kernel mode yet, but I will as soon as possible

Comment: I did try it and it did nothing. after adding nvidia_drm.modeset=1, nothing changed, nor did anything change when i removed kms from mkinitcpio hooks

Comment: I did try it again and found out that i had a typoo. It did non fix the issue BUT it changes output of `xrandr -q` : 
`DP-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)`
now it names devices with dashes

Comment: If you need to add information then please use [edit] to add it to the question, not comments.

Comment: Furthermore you have an incorrect assumption but it has no bearing on the issue. Correcting just in case. The default state in Windows is the equivalent of the "on demand" profile, i.e., use iGPU by default, most of the times and for everything including the integrated screen, toggles to the dGPU only when certain more demanding software is running. Yes, most vendors only connect the external output to the dGPU (the reasoning being that if you're using an external monitor then you have access to an electrical outlet so the battery saving feature of using the iGPU is moot).

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I kind of solved the Issue. 
Short solution: 
Follow [this](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/PRIME) arch linux wiki page, especially section 3.1 and 4.1. That should be enough.
Longer explaination:
I've followed [this arch linux wiki page](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/PRIME), section 3.1 for Reverse PRIME. The Xorg configuration file that I've stolen from that section did not contain BusID for dGPU, but since it was on wiki I thought that it just has to be that way. Of course it did not work and I've searched the solution elsewhere. However, when I was trying this again, I've accidentally copied the config file from section 4.1, and since there were Bus ID's for both GPUs, after running `xrandr --setprovideroutputsource Intel NVIDIA-G` xrandr did see the second monitor and did output to it. But I needed to switch active and inactive screens in config and switch GPUs in the command above since I needed my iGPU to be linked to dGPU, not the other way (It would have been other way though if my second monitor was better). 
This question was also posted on [arch linux forum](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=2126211#p2126211), but the thread did not contain too much extra information.
Note: please do follow the entire wiki page, don't skip steps. Besides changing configuration file in the correct way, I did way to much extra steps that I don't know whether they affect the result (like setting the kernel parameters as I've shown in comments). The guide should be exhaustive in that way.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).